# I'm trying to figure out how to use dbus with pidgin

Tags: python, dbus

My problem is I'm not sure how to interface them. Do I need to have pidgin installed in a particular way in order for dbus to interface with it? and if not does the pidgin gui have to be running in order for dbus to utilize it?

Answer (score 5):

As per [this](http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/dbus-with-pidgin-help-with-changing-messages-from-pointer-518436.html) source you could do the following :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def cb_func(account, rec, message):
    #change message here somehow? 
    print message

import dbus, gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
bus = dbus.SessionBus()

bus.add_signal_receiver(cb_func,
dbus_interface="im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface",
signal_name="SendingImMsg")

loop = gobject.MainLoop()
loop.run()
```

Probably you can get started with this lead.

Answer (score 4):

```
import dbus
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

main_loop = DBusGMainLoop()
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus(mainloop = main_loop)
obj = session_bus.get_object("im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService", "/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject")
purple = dbus.Interface(obj, "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface")
```

Then you can use the purple object to call some methods like this:

```
status = purple.PurpleSavedstatusNew("", current)
purple.PurpleSavedstatusSetMessage(status, message)
purple.PurpleSavedstatusActivate(status)
```

Answer (score 2):

A really useful tool to use when getting started with using DBUS to interface with Pidgin is [D-Feet](https://fedorahosted.org/d-feet/).  You can see all the available methods you can call and even execute them directly from the GUI.

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning D-Feet. Seems to be a really nice dbus debugger tool.

Answer (score 2):

The code below has an example of showing the buddy list when it is hidden and another example of starting an IM conversation with a specific contact.

```
import dbus
BUS_ARGS = ('im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService', '/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject')
obj = dbus.SessionBus().get_object(*BUS_ARGS)
purple = dbus.Interface(obj, 'im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface')

# show buddy list if it is hidden
purple.PurpleBlistSetVisible(1)

# start IM conversation with specific contact
account = purple.PurpleAccountsFindConnected('', '')
conversation = purple.PurpleConversationNew(1, account, 'alice@example.com')
```

I can recommend a number of useful resources relating to using dbus with pidgin:

- [Riding the D-Bus with Pidgin](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2007/05/pidgin-2-0/4/) - Has three separate python dbus examples.
- [purple-remote](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/purple-remote.1.html) - It's a python script that was installed on my ubuntu machine when I installed pidgin. Its a single file and pretty easy to read through.
- [dbus-monitor](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-monitor.1.html) - Great program to monitor dbus calls. It can help you discover what calls are being used by programs you use when you can't find them documented.
- [qdbusviewer](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qdbusviewer.html) - Great graphical tool that can list pidgins dbus methods. You can also call them from the tool itself.

[image: qdbusviewer]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do any special configuration of Pidgin to use D-Bus, however it must be running if you want to use it. You can check the script I'm using to control Pidgin status from the NetworkManager-dispatcher ([part 1](http://github.com/abbot/shredder/blob/master/pidgin-netstatus.py), [part 2](http://github.com/abbot/shredder/blob/master/98-pidgin.sh)) as a sample how to interface Pidgin via D-Bus from python.